# Identity registry replication

Tags: azure-iot-hub, disaster-recovery

I am designing an IoT solution's Disaster Recovery approach on Azure. I am following [IoT Hub High Availability and DR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-ha-dr) in MSDN. The solution need to keep keep geo-replicated backups of device identities from primary, and upload them to the secondary IoT hub before switching the active endpoint for the devices. 
I am not able to find out any documentation on how to take backup of Identity Registry from primary and upload it in secondary.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I should be using IoT Hub Device Identities in bulk - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-bulk-identity-mgmt.

Answer (score 0):

The topic came up today regarding IoT Hubs and DR. It sounds like you are doing the same work. Is there any other information you can share. We have an IoT Hub centric app only in one Regional DataCenter. What happens if an earthquake etc hits the data center. I have to come up with the architecture. Anything that you can share would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! MIke

Comment: Try out this with a Concierge service approach as recommended in MSDN site - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-ha-dr